# Paytm redirect to Callback instead of payment gateway in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, paytm

So, I have integrated Paytm in Symfony 5 following [this](https://vivanwebsolution.com/paytm-payment-gateway-integration-with-symfony-step-by-step/) tutorial.
My problem here is, if I remove callback_url parameter from the `$paytmParams` there I can see the payment gateway but no callback is done ,but still could do a payment. Since Callback_Url is very important when I put back, instead of redirecting to payment gateway it redirects to Callback url returning

```
TXN_FAILURE
```

Following is the COntroller:

```
     public function pay(Request $request, SessionInterface $session){
    $baseurl = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost() . $request->getBasePath();         
    $containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        
    // add service into the service container
    $containerBuilder->register('helper.service', 'App\Helper\PaytmChecksum');        
        $paytmParams = array(
            "MID" => "midmidmidmidmid",
            "WEBSITE" => "WEBSTAGING",
            "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID" => "Retail",
            "CHANNEL_ID" => "WEB",
            "ORDER_ID" => 1,
            "CUST_ID" => 2,
            "EMAIL" => 'example@gmail.com',
            "TXN_AMOUNT" => 300,
            "CALLBACK_URL" => $baseurl.$this->generateUrl('paytmcheckout')
            );
         
        // $checksum = $containerBuilder->get('helper.service')->getChecksumFromArray($paytmParams, "&".$this->container->getParameter('paytm_marchent_key'));
       
       
        $checksum = $containerBuilder->get('helper.service')->generateSignature($paytmParams, 'yfIkKK5nEixN33Y3');   
            // dump($checksum);
            // $session->set('checksum', $checksum);    
        return $this->render('admission/pay.html.twig',[
            'paytmParams' => $paytmParams,
            'checksum' => $checksum,                
        ]);
 }

/**
* @Route("/paytmcheckout", name="paytmcheckout")
*/
//Paytm payment Response function and also use for databse entry.
public function paytmcheckoutAction(Request $request)
{
    $containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    $containerBuilder->register('helper.service', 'App\Helper\PaytmChecksum');

    $token = $containerBuilder->get('helper.service')->VerifierChecksum($request);       
    $status = $request->request->get('STATUS');
    $orderId = $request->request->get('ORDERID');
    $status_code = $request->request->get('STATUSCODE');
// dump($status_code);
//     die; 
    if($token == "TRUE") {
        if ($status == "TXN_SUCCESS") {
        $this->addFlash('messsage','Payment has been successful.');
        }else{
        $this->addFlash('messsage','Payment has been Failed.');
        }
    }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('admission');
}
```

twig: pay.html.twig

```
<form method="post" action="https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/order/process" name="f1">
<table border="1">
<tbody>
 
{% for keyVal, paytmParam in paytmParams %}
<input type="hidden" name="{{ keyVal }}" value="{{ paytmParam }}">
{% endfor %}
<input type="hidden" name="CHECKSUMHASH" value="{{ checksum }}">
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.f1.submit();
</script>
</form>
```

dumping token is true but status is TXN_FAILURE

in url this

> https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/order/process

is seen for a sec and redirects to `@Route("/paytmcheckout", name="paytmcheckout")`

If I have missed elsewhere then please guide me.. Thank you..

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, thanks for the info. If you don't mind can you please guide me?

Comment: I don't know where to start. I think you'd better start with a better example. I see Paytm has a SDK you can use: https://developer.paytm.com/docs/server-sdk/php/?ref=serverSdk

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the tutorial OP used is of exceptional bad quality.